# Conditional event waiting / ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, synchronization, manualresetevent

I know how to use the ManualResetEvent or synchronization primitives (like Monitor) to wait for events and/or locks, but I am wondering if there is a way to implement something like the following:

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent; 

public string WaitForOneThousandMs()
{
    resetEvent.Wait(1000);

    if (WaitTime(resetEvent) <= 1000)
        return "Event occured within 1000ms."; 
    else
        return "Event did not occur within 1000ms."; 
}
```

1) Wait for 1000ms for an event X to occur

2) If event occurs within 1000ms, execute path A

3) Otherwise, execute path B

This is basically a conditional waiting function where the condition is how long we had to wait, what would be the best way to implement it, if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're after:

```
return resetEvent.WaitOne(1000) ? "Event occurred within 1000ms"
                                : "Event did not occur within 1000ms";
```

From the docs for [`WaitHandle.WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx):

> **Return value**
>   *true* if the current instance receives a signal; otherwise, *false*.

[`Monitor.Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syehfawa.aspx) returns a `bool` in a similar fashion.

Comment: Quick follow-up question: If the Set() method is called on ManualResetEvent BEFORE the WaitOne() method even starts waiting, will the WaitOne() method immediately return true?